# How to find a Row in Datagridview and update it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I can show data in GridView, now I need find a row with user input in DataGridView so the cursor moves to this row, get this row and update the field (I want updated fields in a textbox on the form , after update), show updated row in datagridview and cursor move to next row automaticaly

Can someone help me?

Comment: is this `WinForms` or `WPF` ?

Comment: do you use `DataBinding` or just `AddRow(..)` ?

Answer (score 1):

let's say you'r binded data artifact (class is `MyData`)

```
public class MyData 
{  
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Address {get;set}
}
```

so yuo have somewhere a collection of of `MyData` like `List<MyData>`

`List<MyData> myDataList = new List<MyData>();`

and do somewhere in the code, I presume, something like this:

`dataGrid.DataSource=myDataList`

Now, yo want to find some row on `DataGrid`, but you *really* want is to find a **data**. So, make a query over the `myDataList` to find `MyData` object of interest, let's say like this

```
var foundMyData = from data in myDataList where (. condition..) select data;
```

We found the **data** we interested in, so no let-\'s make it selected on `UI`. 
So find the index of the `foundMyData` in the list and select corresponding row on the grid.

If you use `Sorting`, or `View` so the data visible on the screen can be filtered or sorted, you need to consider that "transformations" too, naturally.